# Volley retry request

Tags: android-volley

I am currently testing out the volley library. But when request fails (404) it doesn't get executed again or at least there are no errors.However there is data missing. Is this the right way to retry a request if it has been failed ?

Thanks in advance

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,1,1.0f));
queue.add(req);
```

Usage :

```
JsonObjectRequest req = null;
        for(int i=0;i<profielen.size();i++){
            final int pos = i;
             req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, imageLocUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            setImageOnProfile(pos,response.get("thumbnail").toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


            }}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

            req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,1,1.0f));
            queue.add(req);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not the right way.

Asides:

- HTTP 404 is not a status code I would expect a normally-behaved HTTP
  client under normal condition to retry.
- You most like are receiving an error via the error listener you
  supply to the request, but your error listener is a NOOP so maybe
  you're not noticing?
- (`http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html` has OK
  descriptions of the status code meanings.)
- The request's retry policy only applies to failures due to: open socket timeouts, socket opening timeouts, HTTP 401s and HTTP 403s. All other failures are not automatically retried, AFAIK.

I think that to retry a 404 with Volley you need to retry it by hand in `onErrorResponse`.

(Ficus: it would be nice if the RetryPolicy was consulted for error status codes. I would like to be able to set a policy that retries on 503s.)